# Lost geometry from QGIS mysql vector layer

Tags: qgis, geometry, mysql

I have a vector layer displaying geometry from a mysql view.

This works fine for several days/weeks until suddenly it fails to refresh and my layer reverts to a non-geometry table, losing all symbols, labels etc.

Closing the project without saving and reverting does not revert back to the previous working state. I am able to add a new vector layer to the same view that displays correctly but without my custom symbols.

Is there any way to fix my layer (re-establish the geometry field) without having to start from scratch?

Edit: QGIS 2.18.16, MySQL 5.6.14

Answer (score 1):

Not a fix for the underlying problem, but try to add the layer back as a new vector layer then:

- Layer|Copy style, then
- Layer|Paste style

That should make the newly-added layer match the old style; you can then remove the old layer.

Longer term solution: save the style as the default in the database from the Properties dialog.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response. When I try paste from the old layer I get 'Cannot past style: Cannot apply style to layer with a different geometry type' error. I've remade my styles and saved them as you suggested so hopefully can recover faster next time.

Comment: Looks like there was an [old bug](https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=27300) (MySQL 5.0.x) that had geometry problems in views - can't see anything recent though.

Comment: Update: the default style works for adding the data as a new layer. My vector layer is from a view - could the layer become broken due to the view being altered?

Comment: I haven't used MySQL in a very long time so can't try to reproduce the issue. The bug I link to above matches your symptoms (views / lost geometry), so you might want to update your version (though it references a much older, supposedly fixed one) anyway or search for similar bugs?